# Issue in Parallel execution with multiple browser using Singleton?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, singleton, testng, selenium-grid

Can I do parallel execution with multiple browsers using Singleton? If yes, how.

I am facing issue in my local machine.

Comment: Its hard to tell without seeing the code or knowing what is the problem...

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible to do it, Singleton allows you to make only one instance of a WebDriver that is related to a browser session so it's impossible to do parallel execution with multiple browser

Comment: Thank you @Hamza for the answer. I am able to do parallel execution with a single browser but with multiple browsers, it was not.